Optimizing Asynchronous Requests and Response Handling in Python for Large Datasets
I am working on a Python script where I send a high volume of asynchronous HTTP requests to an external geocoding API, and then handle the responses to update a DataFrame with the geocoded data. The script uses pandas for data management and requests-futures for asynchronous HTTP requests. My goal is to improve the execution speed and ensure robustness against request failures or timeouts.
Here is the main part of my script:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

# Assume df is a DataFrame with ZIP codes and country info
API_KEY = "your_api_key_here"
# Variables for request tracking and timing
request_counter = 0
response_counter = 0
start_time = time.time()

# Initialize session for making asynchronous HTTP requests
session = FuturesSession()


def response_hook(resp, *args, **kwargs):
    """Hook function for handling completion of each future."""
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data for request with params {resp.request.params}: Status {resp.status_code}")

def get_geocode_info(row):
    """Send an asynchronous HTTP request to the geocoding API for each row of data.
    Args:
        row: A dictionary representing a row of data, typically containing ZIP code and country code.    
    Returns:
        Future: A Future object representing the pending HTTP request.
    """
    global request_counter, start_time
    
    # Construct the URL and parameters for the geocoding API request
    url = "https://api.woosmap.com/localities/geocode"
    params = {
        "address": row['zipcode_as_entered'],
        "components": f"country:{row['shop_country_for_request']}",
        "key": API_KEY
    }
    headers = {'Referer': 'http://localhost'}
    
    # Send an asynchronous HTTP GET request
    future = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, hooks={'response': [response_hook]})
    
    """Counter and Status Update:
    """
    # Increment the request counter
    request_counter += 1
    
    # Print status update every 10,000 requests
    if request_counter % 10000 == 0:
        print(f"Number of requests sent: {request_counter}")
        end_time = time.time()
        time_taken = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Time taken for last 10000 requests: {time_taken} seconds")
        start_time = time.time()
    
    return future

# Send asynchronous requests
futures = df.apply(get_geocode_info, axis=1)

# Collect responses
results = [{'wm_address': '', 'wm_latitude': None, 'wm_longitude': None, 'wm_country': '', 'wm_flag': 0} for _ in range(len(df))]

# Iterating over futures to collect responses

for index, future in futures.iteritems():
    response = future.result() # Get the result of the future (HTTP response)
    if response.status_code == 200:  # If the response is successful (status code 200)
        
        """Counter and Status Update:
        """
        response_counter += 1
        if response_counter % 10000 == 0:
            print(f"Number of response received: {response_counter}")
            end_time = time.time()
            time_taken = end_time - start_time
            print(f"Time taken for last 10000 response: {time_taken} seconds")
            start_time = time.time()
            
            
            
        json_data = response.json() # Parse the JSON response
        
        # Extract relevant information from the response and append to results list
        
        if 'results' in json_data and json_data['results']:
            result = json_data['results'][0]
            flag = 1 if str(df.at[index, 'zipcode_as_entered']) == result.get('name', '') else 0
            results[index] = {
                'wm_address': result.get('formatted_address', ''),
                'wm_latitude': result['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                'wm_longitude': result['geometry']['location']['lng'],
                'wm_country': next((comp['long_name'] for comp in result['address_components'] if 'country' in comp['types']), ''),
                'wm_flag': flag
            }
        else:
            # Keep the default values if no results found
            pass
    else:
        # Keep the default values if the request failed
        print(f"Request #{request_counter}: Failed to retrieve data for ZIPCODE {df.at[index, 'zipcode_as_entered']} with status {response.status_code}")

    # Every 10,000 results, update the interim DataFrame 
    if (index + 1) % 10000 == 0 or index + 1 == len(df):
        interim_df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=df.index)
        
    
    
              
# Create DataFrame from results and merge it with the original DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, results_df], axis=1)



Challenges:
This works but I feel the time taken is high - maybe I am doing something wrong that I am overlooking?
Thank you in advance!
